# Binding to a static font in WPF

Tags: wpf, data-binding, static, font-family

I'm having troubles binding to a static FontFamily.

Here's some info about what i'm actually doing.
In the application I want users to chose their font. So i allow them to choose the font at the start then it saves to a file (to make it save the font for next time the user opens the application.) Then i read from the file and store the font in a static variable under the class 'Fonts'. When i use MessageBoxes to display the fonts it works. So the only thing that isn't working is my binding to the font. Please have a look.

```
public class Fonts
{
    private static FontFamily _titleFont;

    /// <summary>
    /// A static property which you'd like to bind to
    /// </summary>
    public static FontFamily titleFont
    {
        get
        {
            return _titleFont;
        }

        set
        {
            _titleFont = value;

            // Raise a change event
            OnTitleFontChanged(EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }

    // Declare a static event representing changes to your static property
    public static event EventHandler TitleFontChanged;

    // Raise the change event through this static method
    protected static void OnTitleFontChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        EventHandler handler = TitleFontChanged;

        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(null, e);
        }
    }
    static Fonts()
    {
        // Set up an empty event handler
        TitleFontChanged += (sender, e) => { return; };

    }

}
```

Then on the start method of window it sets static variable like this:

```
Fonts.titleFont = new FontFamily(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Fonts/#Aldrich", UriKind.Absolute), "Aldrich");
```

The Textblocks fontfammily is set like this:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="CurrentUserStatsTitle" FontSize="36" Text="Welcome, " Foreground="White" FontFamily="{Binding Path=(local:Fonts.titleFont)}"/>
```

How it looks:
[image: Ho]

How it's supposed to look: [image]

Update:

This is how the code looks now. everything runs just fine but my binding is still not working. Is there anything i'm doing wrong ? if so can you explain or send me a link to a explained solution?

```
public class Fonts
{
    private static FontFamily _titleFont;

    /// <summary>
    /// A static property which you'd like to bind to
    /// </summary>
    public static event PropertyChangedEventHandler StaticPropertyChanged;

    public static FontFamily TitleFont
    {
        get { return _titleFont; }
        set
        {
            _titleFont = value;
            StaticPropertyChanged?.Invoke(null,
                new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(TitleFont)));
        }
    }

    private static FontFamily _subTitleFont;

    /// <summary>
    /// A static property which you'd like to bind to
    /// </summary>
    public static FontFamily SubTitleFont
    {
        get { return _subTitleFont; }
        set
        {
            _subTitleFont = value;
            StaticPropertyChanged?.Invoke(null,
                new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(SubTitleFont)));
        }
    }

    private static FontFamily _descriptionFont;

    /// <summary>
    /// A static property which you'd like to bind to
    /// </summary>
    public static FontFamily DescriptionFont
    {
        get { return _descriptionFont; }
        set
        {
            _descriptionFont = value;
            StaticPropertyChanged?.Invoke(null,
                new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(DescriptionFont)));
        }
    }
    static Fonts()
    {
        StaticPropertyChanged += (sender, e) => { return; };
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the purpose of the "empty event handler"? Also the OnTitleFontChanged method looks odd. Do you ever pass anything else than `EventArgs.Empty` as argument?

Comment: Any fontfamily with a relative path will leak memory. That's a relative path.

Comment: Did you also change the property name in the Binding, to `Path=(local:Fonts.TitleFont)`?

Comment: Yes i did i found the solution i'll post it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a name mismatch between your static property and its changed event.

If the property is named `titleFont`, the corresponding event must be named `titleFontChanged`.

And of course there are widely accepted naming conventions, according to which property names should use Pascal casing, i.e. start with an uppercase letter.

So the property should perhaps better be named `TitleFont`.

---

IMO, a better solution for the implementation of static property change notification would be to have a single `StaticPropertyChanged` event for all static properties:

```
public static event PropertyChangedEventHandler StaticPropertyChanged;

public static FontFamily TitleFont
{
    get { return _titleFont; }
    set
    {
        _titleFont = value;
        StaticPropertyChanged?.Invoke(null,
            new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(TitleFont)));
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll try this right now. I'm not very knowledgeable of the entire notifyproperty changed thing

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Clemens and Andy i have found the answer.

The Code Clemens provided works well and all. But the problem was that there are memory leaks when i was using the relative path.

I followed the instructions found on the following site:
https://github.com/ButchersBoy/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/issues/746

This solved my issue.

Comment: Do you mean the static property binding did not work at all? Memory leak seems to be an entirely different problem than a not working binding.

Comment: Well my Binding code was wrong and you helped me with that but then i had the other issue of the memory leak... So i kinda ended up with 2 problems